# Quadratic equation with parameters

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a$, $b$, $c$ are real numbers such that $2a + 3b + 6c = 0$, prove that $ax^2+bx +c=0$ has a solution in the interval $[0, 1]$.

This should use high school maths or a little bit more then that.

Comment: Ok i just don't understand why you chose $f(1/2)$.

Comment: If you want to respond the answer, do comment under the answer, this ensure the one who answered being informed.  No one can review all questions answered all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  0 &= 2a+3b+6c \\
  f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
  f(0) &= c \\
  f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) &= \frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{2}+c \\
  &= -\frac{a}{12} \\
  f(1) &= a+b+c \\
  &= \frac{a}{3}-c
\end{align*}

**Case I:** $ac \ge 0$

$$f(0) f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = -\frac{ac}{12} \le  0$$

- $\exists x\in \left[ 0, \dfrac{1}{2} \right]$ such that $f(x)=0$.

**Case II:** $ac \le 0$

$$f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) f(1)= -\frac{a^2}{36}+\frac{ac}{12} \le  0$$

- $\exists x\in \left[ \dfrac{1}{2}, 1 \right]$ such that $f(x)=0$.

> Combining, $\exists x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$

**N.B.**

When $0 <3ac <a^2$, there're **two such roots**, namely $\alpha \in \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right)$ and  $\beta \in \left( \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right)$.

**Updates**

The value of $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ can be inspired by plotting a family of curves by varying either $b$ or $c$.  You can see a fixed point at $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ by varying $c$ below.

[image]

Alternatively, $(x,y)=\left(\dfrac{1}{2},-\dfrac{a}{12} \right)$ is a solution of

$$ax^2-\left( \frac{2a}{3} + 2c \right)x+c-y=
\frac{\partial}{\partial c}
\left[
  ax^2-\left( \frac{2a}{3} + 2c \right)x+c-y
\right]=0$$

Comment: Nice Solution Ng Chung Tak, But i did not understand your alternate solution , specially $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial c}
\left[
  ax^2-\left( \frac{2a}{3} + 2c \right)x+c-y
\right]=0$

Comment: That's from theory of [**envolope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)).  If it's beyond your level, just ignore it.